# Terraform complaining about list being used in lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform

I have a lambda where I am passing a list in order to obtain an attribute from it. The list ENV_LIST has more than 1 element. When I try run a terraform plan it seems to be complaining about the variable ENV_LIST. I have specified it to be a list in my variables.tf file and referencing it in my lamnda.tf but still its complaining.

`Error: aws_lambda_function.lambda_function: environment.0.variables (ENV_LIST): '' expected type 'string', got unconvertible type '[]interface {}'`

lambda.tf

```
   environment {
    variables = {
      DB_NAME_LIST = "${var.db_name_list}"
      ENV_LIST     = "${var.env_list}"
    }
  }
```

variables.tf

```
variable "db_name_list" {
  type = "list"
}
variable "env_list" {
  type = "list"
}
```

Comment: Environmental variables in lambda functions must be strings. Create a comma separated string out of your list and use that.

Comment: env_list is reffering a json file which is a variable inside it. It is a comma separated list as so :  "env_list": ["pp3", "pp4", "pn1"]

Comment: You should show all the relevant code in your question, including the definition of `var.env_list` and `var.db_name_list`. If you want to convert a Terraform list into a single string you probably need to use the Terraform `join` function https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/join.html

Comment: So i need to convert my list in to a single string as so : 

 ENV_LIST     = join("," , "${var.env_list}")  @MarkB

Comment: Lambda functions only take environment variables that are strings. What is your end goal? Do you want to pass each value as a separate environment variable to the Lambda function, or do you want to pass them all as a single string and then parse that string back into a list inside the Lambda function? You should include the desired result in your initial question.

Comment: @MarkB- i just want the values in a list which i pass into the lambda function. I do not need a single string

Comment: @devdude - you _do_ need a single string, because that's how environment variables work. So use `join()`, or `jsonencode()`, or whatever you like to turn your list into a sting, and parse it within your Lambda to turn it back into a list.

Answer (score 0):

```
variable "db_names" {
  type        = list(string)
  description = "db_names"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "function" {
  function_name    = "${var.name_prefix}-function${local.name_suffix}"
  description      = "Function"
  filename         = var.filename
  source_code_hash = var.source_code_hash
  runtime          = "nodejs14.x"
  handler          = "index.handler"
  timeout          = var.timeout
  memory_size      = var.memory_size
  role             = var.lambda_role_arn
  environment {
    variables = {
      DB_NAMES       = join(",", var.db_names)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Daniel, works perfect. Using `join` function Lambda Environment variable `DB_NAMES` is updated into a single string.

```
locals {
  db_names = ["/aws/lambda/foo", "/aws/lambda/bar"]
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "function" {
  function_name    = "${var.name_prefix}-function${local.name_suffix}"
  description      = "Function"
  filename         = var.filename
  source_code_hash = var.source_code_hash
  runtime          = "nodejs14.x"
  handler          = "index.handler"
  timeout          = var.timeout
  memory_size      = var.memory_size
  role             = var.lambda_role_arn
  environment {
    variables = {
      DB_NAMES       = join(",", local.db_names)
    }
  }
}
```